# "Error detected while processing /Users/mycomputer/.vimrc:" when I try to open a file

Tags: vimrc, macos

New to vim. I'm on MacOS and every time I do `vim something.txt`, it gives me

```
Error detected while processing /Users/mycomputer/.vimrc:
line  128:
E471: Argument required
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Everything works fine after I press ENTER.
What could be the issue?

This is around line 128 in .vimrc if this helps:

```
    if count(s:opam_available_tools,"ocp-indent") == 0
  source "/Users/anyaji/.opam/4.09.0/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim"
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:source` should be without quotes:

```
:source "/Users/anyaji/.opam/4.09.0/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim"
E471: Argument required

:source /Users/anyaji/.opam/4.09.0/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim
E484: Can't open file /Users/anyaji/.opam/4.09.0/share/ocp-indent/vim/indent/ocaml.vim
```

This file doesn't exist on my system, but as you can see the "argument required" error message went away and got replaced by a more suitable one :-) VimScripts are just sequences of commands you can type in the `:` commandline, so this is usually an easy way to debug stuff.

Why do you get the "Argument required" error? VimScript has the somewhat unusual choice of `"` as the comment character, so the file path is seen as a comment, and the command Vim sees is just `:source`  without argument.